# Varieties and subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm studying for my last exam and I got stuck in this exercise, from Fulton of Algebraic Geometry.

Let $V$ be an affine variety, $f\in \Gamma(V)$

a) Prove that $V(f) = \{P\in V | f(P)=0\}$ is a closed subset of $V$, and $V(f)\neq V$, unless that $f=0$.

b) Suppose that $U$ is a dense subset of $V$ and $f(P)=0$ for all $P\in U$. Then $f=0$

If anyone can give me a hint I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) This follows from the definition of the Zariski topology.  Let $F \in k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ be a representative for $f$.  Then $V(f) = V \cap V(F)$ which is closed in $V$.  ($V(F)$ is Zariski closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$, so $V \cap V(F)$ is closed in $V$ by definition of the subspace topology.)

Can you figure out the rest of a)?  What does it mean if $f = 0$ in $\Gamma(V)$?  What does it mean for $F$?  **Hint:** Consider $I(V)$.

b)  Since $f(P) = 0$ for all $P \in U$, then $U \subseteq V(f)$.  In part a) we showed that $V(f)$ is closed.  What can you say about the closure $\overline{U}$?  Recall that $\overline{U}$ is the *smallest* closed set containing $U$.